# Page build failure on Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I created a new post at https://github.com/IvanPsy/ivanferreroit/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2016-09-27-risolvere-emozioni-negative.md but the page failed to build due to datetime.
I'm reviewing the post again and again, I made many edits but the page still fails to build.

Where's the mistake?
How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: The link is inaccessible. Can you paste the contents of the file or make it public? Also, can you paste the contents of the Jekyll build error?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's because the front matter is invalid. The description has a colon in it, so the value needs to be quoted.

From https://github.com/IvanPsy/ivanferreroit/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2016-09-26-risolvere-emozioni-negative.md:

```
description: Rabbia, irascibilità, sconforto, delusione, dolore, rigidità, ossessività, ira, invidia: quante volte proviamo queste emozioni, e tante altre? E dopo averle provate? I sensi di colpa.
```

Should be:

```
description: 'Rabbia, irascibilità, sconforto, delusione, dolore, rigidità, ossessività, ira, invidia: quante volte proviamo queste emozioni, e tante altre? E dopo averle provate? I sensi di colpa.'
```

It's rather unfortunate that the error is related to the date!